# React-router - Link firing too soon

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have just begun to integrate react-router into my application, and it's working like a charm. However, I do have one small problem. At one point I need to click on a button which changes to a different page but also needs to make an action call (which goes to the server and gets the data to be shown in the table). At the moment the react-router link is firing before the action and therefore breaking the app at this point, as there is no data to map through!

My question is how I can change the order in which these events happen so that there is data present in a store (updated by the action) when the page is changed?

Current code block:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import List from 'material-ui/lib/lists/list';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/lib/lists/list-item';
import ActionInfo from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/info';
import { getTable } from '../../actions/DALIActions';
import TokenStore from '../../stores/TokenStore';
import TableStore from '../../stores/TableStore';

const styles = {
    root: {
        paddingTop: 200,
        width: '100%',
    },
    headerStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    container: {
        border: 'solid 1px #d9d9d9',
        height: 500,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
};

class MainTablePage extends React.Component {

    getTable(id) {
        getTable(TokenStore.getToken(), id);
    }

    addTables() {
        let tableArray = TableStore.getTables().objects;
        console.log(tableArray);
        let tableList = tableArray.map((el, i) => {
            return (
                <ListItem
                    key={i}
                    id={el.id}
                    primaryText={el.title}
                    leftIcon={<ActionInfo />}
                    containerElement={<Link to="/table" />}
                    linkButton={true}
                    onTouchTap={this.getTable.bind(this, el.id)} 
                />
            );
        });
        return tableList;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={styles.headerStyle}>
                    <h1>Here are the current tables available</h1>
                </div>
                <div style={styles.root}>
                    <div style={styles.container}>
                        <List>
                            {this.addTables()}
                        </List>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainTablePage;
```

Oh yeah, I'm using material-ui so that probably doesn't help matters!

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try putting you API call in `componentDidMount`, then `setState` when the data is returned, thereby re-rendering the view. See here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Comment: Would you rather have the user wait after clicking OR would you change the page and wait for the API to finish off and show a loader in the meanwhile.
Because API call will take some time and if you do not change page, the user will press the button again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire the action within the components `componentDidMount()` and set a loading state within your store.

When the action is fired and a request is made set the loading state to true. Once the data is fetched set it back to false. This way you're rendering a loader instead of components that rely on data that hasn't been fetched.

I updated to your code to show how it would work. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Here is a link to React's [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) for more information.

```
class MainTablePage extends React.Component {
     componentDidMount() {
         // fire your action here
     }
     getTable(id) {
         getTable(TokenStore.getToken(), id);
     }

     addTables() {
        let tableArray = TableStore.getTables().objects;
        console.log(tableArray);
        let tableList = tableArray.map((el, i) => {
            return (
                <ListItem
                    key={i}
                    id={el.id}
                    primaryText={el.title}
                    leftIcon={<ActionInfo />}
                    containerElement={<Link to="/table" />}
                    linkButton={true}
                    onTouchTap={this.getTable.bind(this, el.id)} 
                />
            );
        });
        return tableList;
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.props; // loading state from your store

        if (loading) {
            // return a loader component while your data is fetched
            return <Loader />;       
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div style={styles.headerStyle}>
                    <h1>Here are the current tables available</h1>
                </div>
                <div style={styles.root}>
                    <div style={styles.container}>
                        <List>
                            {this.addTables()}
                        </List>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry about this but I didn't really have time to properly go through your answer. While this is similar to what I am trying to achieve, the action is being called so that the data will be available in the next page not on the page that I am currently on. By the logic that you presented I guess that I should be calling the action in that component, but as it requires an id argument (as can be seen in the getTable function, where I am calling the action at the moment), can I do this with componentDidMount? I was under the impression that it didn't take any arguments?!

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks again for the point in the right direction!

Comment: Hey! Sorry about the late reply I should turn on notifications. And glad I could point you in the right direction!